# Hibernate and DAO (CRUD). Create new user keeps overriding the same person ID

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, crud, dao

So I am having a little trouble trying to get my create user function to work. I am trying to create a new user for every new user entry from the Scanner console, but my Hibernate is updating the same person ID, instead of assigning a new person ID to the new user.

my DAO class:

```
    public void createDoctor(Doctor doctor) {
    sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(doctor);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close();
}
```

my main class:

```
    int adminNum = sc.nextInt();

        if (adminNum == 1) {
            System.out.print("Please enter doctor's first name: ");
            sc.nextLine();
            String firstName = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Please enter doctor's last name: ");
            String lastName = sc.nextLine();
            Doctor d = new Doctor();
            d.setFirstName(firstName);
            d.setLastName(lastName);

            doctorList.add(d);
            int index = doctorList.indexOf(d);
            dao.createDoctor(doctorList.get(index));

        }
```

Doctor Class:

```
    import java.util.*;

    import javax.persistence.*;

    @Entity
    public class Doctor extends Person {

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "SPECIALTY_ID")
private Specialty specialty;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "doctor", targetEntity = Patient.class,fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade= CascadeType.ALL )
private List<Patient> patients;

private double salary;


public Doctor(){
    patients = new ArrayList<Patient>();
}

public void setSalary(double salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

public double getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSpecialty(Specialty specialty) {
    this.specialty = specialty;
}

public Specialty getspecialty() {
    return specialty;
}

public void setPatient(Patient patient){
    patients.add(patient);
}
public List<Patient> getPatients(){
    return patients;
}
    }
```

Person Class:

```
    package edu.cs157b.medicalSystem;

    import javax.persistence.*;

    @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
    public class Person {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
@Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
private int personId;
private String first_name;
private String last_name;
private char sex;

public Person() {

}

public int getPersonId() {
    return personId;
}

public void setPersonId(int personId) {
    this.personId = personId;
}

public void setFirstName(String first_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return first_name;
}

public void setLastName(String last_name) {
    this.last_name = last_name;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return last_name;
}

public void setSex(char sex){
    this.sex = sex;
}

public char getSex(){
    return sex;
}

    }
```

Comment: Would you post the Doctor code (and the mapping if it´s needed)?

Comment: 2 small questions that might help a better understanding: 1. Is the `equals` method of class `Doctor` overwritten? Please post the entire `Doctor` class. 2. Where is `doctorList` declared and instantiated? Please post extended code snippet that includes also this part.

Comment: What equals method? The doctorList is declared and instantiated as a global after main. `List<Doctor> doctorList = new ArrayList<Doctor>();`

Comment: show the `Person` code

Comment: I guess the `@Id` column is declared in `Person`. Could you post that as well?

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this code much.

Personally, I'd prefer having a ctor that did something rather than a do-nothing default ctor and having to call setters.

I'd persist the Doctor, then add it to the List.

Is this synchronized?  Doesn't look thread safe if that List is shared, mutable data.

I see no equals or hashCode implemented here.  That might explain it.  Best to use the primary key fields to determine equality.

I think you're desperately in need of a tutorial.  Forget your assignment for a moment and do something simple:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/tutorial.html

Comment: Well, this assignment is due soon so I am just trying to get the functionality working. I will fix things up and make the code nicer if I have time after the assignment is turned in. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong that won't make a new user every time I run the tester?

Comment: Your urgency isn't our problem.  You didn't post anything that would help answer the question.  Your mapper could be wrong; you might not have implemented equals and hashCode properly.

Comment: I apologize. I did not mean to sound rude.

Comment: I am simply following some of the examples that were given by my professor. I am still fairly new to Hibernate and all its annotations. So would Hibernate still work if there were no getter and setter methods? I guess you can annotate the variables instead because I know Hibernate is strict about where you place your annotations.

Comment: I didn't say no getters/setters.  I think you want to annotate the first and last name fields.  You won't be saving them the database otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Person` class declare the id field as `Integer` so that newly created instances will have null value as `personId`. The primitive `int` type will always have `0` as initial value.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
@Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
private Integer personId;
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. I am still getting this in my Eclipse console when I compile:
`Hibernate: select sequence_next_hi_value from hibernate_sequences where sequence_name = 'Person' for update
Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequences(sequence_name, sequence_next_hi_value) values('Person', ?)
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequences set sequence_next_hi_value = ? where sequence_next_hi_value = ? and sequence_name = 'Person'
Hibernate: insert into Doctor (first_name, last_name, sex, salary, SPECIALTY_ID, PERSON_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

Comment: I see no problem in that log. Hibernates updates the next sequence value (because you are using TABLE strategy for id generation) then inserts the new Person with the current id.

Comment: I asked my friend and he told me to change my hibernate configuration xml from 'create' to 'update' and now it works. But I get an arbitrary large number for the Person_ID. I'm not exactly sure if this is the correct way to go about this problem.      `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>`

Comment: that property controls how to run the ddl scripts for your database. `create` means it will always recreate the entire schema on startup. changing it to `update` simply could not solve your issue.